# Place src value form javascript to img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to put the image source which i am getting perfectly to the `<img/>` place but i don't know how to.

**js:**

```
var aa = document.getElementById("TableImage"+getid).src;
alert(aa);

Result of above js:
```

[image: <code>Result</code>]

**Now i want to place this link here:**

```
<!-- Upload Part -->
<div class="ImageUpload">
    <label for="FileInput" style="width: 18px; height: 18px; margin-top: -160px; margin-left: 905px;">
        <img class="UplaodPic" src="../../img/Upload_Panel.png"/>
   </label>

    <input name="picture" id="FileInput" type="file" onchange="readURL(this,'Picture2')" style="cursor: pointer; display: none"/>
</div>
```

I want to replace `Upload_Panel.png` image with the image in the source `aa`. Help would be nice.

Comment: You may be having issues because upload is spelt wrong in the img tag.

Comment: hey thankyou so much. I didn't even see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$("#FileInput").prev("label").find("img").attr("src", aa);
```

(Since this was the only element with an ID, I went with that. No idea how many of those classes you have on your page)

Comment: that worked for me. will accept your answer in 11 mins

Answer (score 1):

```
var aa = document.getElementById("TableImage"+getid).src;
$('.uplaodPic').attr('src', aa)
```